# Where can I see Cisco IPSec VPN logs?

Tags: macos, vpn, logs

I'm running Sierra and trying to connect to VPN network using a certificate. When I press the Connect button I get an error:

> An unexpected error occurred. Try reconnecting. If the problem continues, verify your settings and contact your Administrator.

[image]

I wonder where I can see the logs of connection attempt because the error message is not clear at all. I saw some advices on the internet about checking `/var/log/system.log`, but there is nothing related to VPN on my machine. Maybe I should somehow enable DEBUG logging?

Answer (score 2):

This information is available in the Console application. The logging for `Cisco IPSec` VPN type is associated with the "racoon" service heading (note: only one `c` in `racoon`); the logging for `IKEv2` is associated with the `nesessionmanager` service. It is unclear to me whether these messages are captured in a persistent log, but they do at least show up when `Console` is open and a VPN connection is created/initiated.